# How to open a .pdf file with a partially matching name in the QGIS open file action

Tags: qgis, actions

I have an attribute table where a field called "IDENT" contains a unique string for each measurement site.

Using the QGIS action open - open file

I  managed to open a PDF in a subfolder if the filename is the same as the IDENT
using the action text like
`[%'./bohrarchiv/'||"IDENT"||'.pdf'%]`

Now I was trying to create an action which would let me open a PDF named 'IDENT [and sth. else].pdf' in the same subfolder.

Is there a way to parse some kind of wildcard (% or LIKE) to the open action? I am using Windows 10.